# Canvas entity constructor

Tags: javascript, canvas

i'm trying to make a sort of constructor so it will be easier in the future to create entities. now i got the first couple things done to make a player but it's not seeing the functions inside of the entity function.

My error : Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

My code :

```
(function () {
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 var entity = function(type,x,y,vx,vy,life) {
    var self = {
        x : canvas.width / 2,
        y : canvas.height / 2,
        vx : 5,
        vy : 5,
        life : 100,
        pressingDown : false,
        pressingUp : false,
        pressingLeft : false,
        pressingRight : false
    };

    if(self.type == 'player') {
        alert('we got a player');
    };

    self.update = function(){
        self.updatePosition();
        self.draw();
    };
    self.updatePosition = function(){
        console.log('position');
    };
    self.draw = function(){
        console.log('drawing');
    };
};

var actor = function(type,x,y,vx,vy,life) {
    var self = entity(type, 25, 25, 5, 5, 100);
    return self;
};

var Player = function() {
    var p = actor('player', 25, 25, 5, 5, 100);
    p.pressingDown = false;
    p.pressingUp = false;
    p.pressingLeft = false;
    p.pressingRight = false;
};

var update = function(){
    player.update();
};

var player = new Player();

setInterval(function(){
    update();
},30)


})();
```

Can anyone spot what i'm doing wrong here? THANKS ALOT!

Comment: Got it to work by adding return self; at the bottom of the entity function, thanks tho everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Player has no `update` method please notice you are using `new` in thix context

```
var Player = function() {
    var p = actor('player', 25, 25, 5, 5, 100);
    p.pressingDown = false;
    p.pressingUp = false;
    p.pressingLeft = false;
    p.pressingRight = false;

    this.update = p.update; //<<<<< here
};

var update = function(){
    player.update();
};

var player = new Player();
```

---

also I want to add you should stick to one method of creating objects

```
var Entity = function(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.z = z; 
}
var e = new Entity(1,2,3);
```

or

```
var entity = function(x, y, z) {
    var obj {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        z: z
    }
    return obj;
}
var e = entity(1,2,3);
```

otherwise your code will be more and more unreadable and you'll end with problems like that more often

Comment: Yeah but it sends stuff to the actor to the entity, this should be recognized there right? or am i retarded

Comment: @Wesleyvans please notice you are using `new` only in one place https://jsfiddle.net/7xsrg50v/. You are mixing lot of stuff there and in order to answer your question I would have to explain all javascript basics